# Derivative of indicator

Tags: functions, derivatives

I have a constant $X_i$ and a function

$f(x) = 1$ if $X_i \leq x$, and $f(x) = 0$ otherwise.

What is $f'(x)$?

Comment: Undefined at x and 0 elsewhere.

Comment: As a distribution the derivative is $f'(x) = \delta(x-X_i)$.

Answer (score 0):

If $x<X_i$ then $\frac{f(x)-f(X_i)}{x-X_i}=\frac{-1}{x-X_i}$. This shows that $f$ is not differentiable at $X_i$.

On the other hand we have: $f$ is differentiable at each $x_0 \ne X_i$ and $f'(x_0)=0$.